# Python script executed twice with Eclipse PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, python-import

I have a project named automated_vertica in Eclipse PyDev, with following architecture :

```
automated_vertica
    src
        root
            __init__.py
            RequestHandler.py
```

RequestHandler.py is a module with a bunch of methods and nothing else.

`__init__.py` contains just two lines:

```
from root import RequestHandler
print('test')
```

When I run `__init__.py` in PyDev, Eclipse console reads `test` twice. If I remove the `from root`, it works just fine.

Can you please explain what I'm missing and what's happening here ?

EDIT: content of RequestHandler.py

```
'''
Created on Apr 23, 2014

@author: myname
'''
def FileToString(fileName): 
    f = open(fileName, 'r')
    result = f.read() 
    f.close()
    return result

def Flatten(listOfLists):
        return [value for sublist in listOfLists for value in sublist]
```

Comment: What's in `RequestHanlder.py`?

Comment: I've added the content of this module

Comment: But even with an empty module, issue happens.

Comment: Wait a minute. Is that `from root import...` in `__init__.py` or in `init.py`?

Comment: `__init__.py` (it just wrote it in bold when I typed it in my question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `root` has an `__init__` file, it's a module.

When you run a `from module import..`, it executes any code in that modules `__init__`.

And since your `__init__` contains a `print`, that gets executed.

Since you're running `__init__` directly (Which you shouldn't do btw), it's doing the following:

```
-> from root import RequestHandler
    -> root.__init__:
        -> import RequestHandler
        -> print("Test")
-> print("Test")
```

The `__init__` is useful for checking presence of any modules, or fallbacks, or checking a python version.

For example, this `__init__.py` will not let any versions of Python less than 400 import the module:

```
import sys

if not hasattr(sys, "version_info") or sys.version_info < (400, 0):
    raise RuntimeError("root requires Python 400.0 or later.")

del sys

from root import RequestHandler
print("Test")
```

Let's hope it updates til the end of time then.

Comment: And if I just put `import RequestHandler`, it doesn't execute `__init__.py`?
Also, where should I put my print, if not in `__init__.py` ?

Comment: Correct. As it's importing locally (As it's in the same directory) rather than from the module. You can keep the print in the `__init__` if you so wish, but I'm not sure why you would. Put it in the code you're executing - the main `whatever.py` that is your main program.